# vehicle detection and tracking in android

Tags: java, android, opencv, machine-learning, detection

I am currently working on an android application to detect and track any type of vehicles moving on a particular road. I am currently using openCV library to do this. After so many days of reading, I have got to realize that i need to use BackgroundSubtractorMOG to detect movement but then how do i identify the object to be vehicle in particular. 
I busted into two different concepts viz: cascade classifiers and optical flow. Don't really know if any of these is what i need.
I actually got a haar classifier [here](https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades) which I tried to implement in the following code snippet:

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mRgb = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    backgroundSubtractorMOG2.apply(mGray, mFGMask, 0.5d);

   //morphological opening 
    Imgproc.erode(mFGMask, mFGMask, new Mat());
    Imgproc.dilate(mFGMask, mFGMask, new Mat());
   //morphological closing
    Imgproc.dilate(mFGMask, mFGMask, new Mat());
    Imgproc.erode(mFGMask, mFGMask, new Mat());

  //mJavaDetector was earlier defined as
  // mJavaDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());

    MatOfRect vehicles = new MatOfRect();
    if (mJavaDetector != null) {
        mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mFGMask, vehicles, 1.1, 1, 2, new Size(0,0), new Size());
    }
    Rect[] vehiclesArray = vehicles.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < vehiclesArray.length; i++)
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgb, vehiclesArray[i].tl(), vehiclesArray[i].br(), VEHICLE_RECT_COLOR, 3)
    return this.mRgb;
}
```

Upon running this, am not getting any sign of detection on the screen.
**My questions are:**

1. Is this project feasible at all in android?
2. If yes, what best approach would you suggest?
3. Is it possible to count these vehicles?
4. Is it possible to also classify vehicles into categories?

Comment: To get good answers for this type of multi concepts involved question, you better have good tags, not only android and openCV.

Comment: @sandesh Thanks for the observation. I have edited it to reflect more tags.